# Apple documentation does not show method return type

Tags: objective-c, nsdate

I'am a newbie starting to learn iOS Development.

How do I know what is the type of returned property or method in Foundation Framework from apple documentation.

I read apple documentation but it does not say about return type.

For example

```
timeIntervalSince1970

    Instance Property
    timeIntervalSince1970
    Language
    SwiftObjective-C
    SDKs
    iOS 2.0+
    macOS 10.0+
    tvOS 9.0+
    watchOS 2.0+
    The interval between the date object and 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970.

    Declaration

         @property(readonly) NSTimeInterval timeIntervalSince1970;

    Discussion

    # This property’s value is negative if the date object is earlier than 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970.
```

`timeIntervalSince1970` returns float, why apple documentation do not mention about it? How will I know return type of other Class methods, instance methods, properties?

Comment: The return type is mentioned in the declaration you posted. It is not `float`, it is `NSTimeInterval`

Comment: ...And `NSTimeInterval` is a Double...

Comment: ... Precisely (which can be accessed by looking up `NSTimeInterval`)

Comment: @aventador: One more tip: if you are using have the function in a Cocoa class for example (such as an .m file) you can usually option + click the name and get valueable info that way also...